# How to change prometheus alert manager port address

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have downloaded prometheus alert manager from prometheus.io and try to run it.

Alert manager is not running because some of our internal applications are running on the port 9093.

So i need to change the alert manager running port from 9093 to some other port say 3002.

How to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `alertmanager` binary with a [`--web.listen-address`](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/bef850ac905cade91423789615de31b9d0288b3d/cmd/alertmanager/main.go#L170) option. For example:

```
alertmanager --web.listen-address=http://localhost:9876
alertmanager --web.listen-address=http://:9876
```

This flag was added [some time ago](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/commit/957d108e67ea80de3e8ea1479a22c7419fa58afd) and can be found in output of `alertmanager -h` command.

Comment: Tried ./alertmanager --web.listen-address=localhost:9876 and working fine